# BQ M10 Ubuntu Touch System Update Fails

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bq

I got my BQ M10 Ubuntu Touch tablet in the mail last week.

When I check for system updates, it starts to download a 500MB update labeled Version 3, but each time I complete that same download, it fails to apply the update.

I've installed the terminal app and the file manager app so far, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Is it the same a Ubuntu desktop? Should I just try to do it from the command line

```
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade
```

???

Comment: If the download is complete it should restart the device and install it. That takes a little time. Is that happened? If not, what happened in your case?

Comment: After the download completes, it soon gives a notification that the System Update was Unsuccessful. I took a screen-shot of it, but it turned out to be a black square the same dimensions as the screen.

Comment: If you start the terminal app and write: "sudo apt update" what are the last 3 lines that appear.

Comment: Numerous "W: Failed to Fetch" statements followed by "W: Not using locking for read only lock file". I need a way to control this tablet using my laptop, so I can do things like this faster. I wish I could rdp or vnc  or ssh into it.

Comment: Hmm... A last idea is to flash the tablet with the ubuntu touch system.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I'd have to learn to do that soon. Oh well, I need to get my touch skills in line with my desktop skills anyway.

Comment: How to flash a new ubuntu-touch system onto a device: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/#install-ubuntu

Comment: While you can mount your root partition a writable and use apt-get you should avoid doing that on Ubuntu Touch or snappy based installations, OTA updates will revert these modifications and will cause filesystem inconsistencies up to non-functional devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to my tablet as well, there seems to be an issue with the update if it's running in the background leave the settings app running in the foreground or on side stage and it should work. Or at least it worked for me on my second attempt this way.

apt-get won't work because the file system isn't writable.

Comment: @JOnathanJOnes : I went to Settings > Battery and set it to never sleep and then tried the update again. When I woke up today, the download button had changed to an install button on the 500MB download. I hit the install button and it asked me to restart about 5 minutes later. After restart, the splash screen became a nice ubuntu progress indicator and now the update is applied.

Comment: I should also note that I also had the USB plugged into my laptop, which was turned on, so that the battery would not run down while I was sleeping. Additionally, unfortunately, the screen was on all night because I cannot figure out how to tell the tablet to NOT go to sleep, but yet save battery by turning the screen (only) off. I think that maybe the reason I had so many prior failed attempts was due to it going to sleep, or sometimes it was due to what ShaneQful said: I was doing other things on the tablet while that update was downloading.